# Unable to write datatable into Excel c#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to save the `data table` values into excel. I have a `Load Report` button from which I am getting data into a grid view.

**Load Report Button  Code**

```
private void BtnInvHD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = @"C:\Output\Log\HavingDuesLog";
        if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }
        string location = Path.Combine(dir, "HavingDues_log_"+name+"_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy_hh:mm:ss") + ".xls");
        string cs = LoginForm.cs;
        date = dtPicker.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            cnn.Open();
        }
        
   
        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("RptIV030", cnn);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", date);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlSda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        sqlSda.Fill(dtData);
        dGInvHD.DataSource = dtData;
        
        writeExcelFile(location,dtData);
        btnExport.Enabled = true;
        //return dtData;
    }
```

**Write to Excel Function**

```
public void writeExcelFile(string location, DataTable read)
    {        
        

        //Create excel app object
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlSamp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        if (xlSamp == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Excel is Not Installed");
            //Console.WriteLine("Excel is not Insatalled");
            //Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }

        //Create a new excel book and sheet
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


        xlWorkBook = xlSamp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        // get the reference of first sheet.
        // store its reference to worksheet 
        xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
        // changing the name of active sheet
        xlWorkSheet.Name = "Having Dues-" + name + "-Till-" + date;
        // column headings
        for (var i = 0; i < read.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = read.Columns[i].ColumnName;
        }
        // rows
        for (var i = 0; i < read.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // to do: format datetime values before printing
            for (var j = 0; j < read.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = read.Rows[i][j];
            }
        }


        //Save the opened excel book to custom location
        //Dont forget, you have to add to exist location
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(location, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlSamp.Quit();

        //release Excel Object 
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSamp);
            xlSamp = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            xlSamp = null;
         
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }

    }
```

When I execute my code am  I able to view data into gridview but unable to write it into an excel file.

I am getting error at `xlWorkBook.SaveAs(location, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);`

**Error Message**

> The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:
>
> ```
> Make sure the specified folder exists. 
> Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.
> Make sure the filename and folder path do not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or  *
> Make sure the filename and folder path do not contain more than 218 characters.
> ```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use something Like this I think its useful:

```
 xlSamp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(filepath, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
                        xlSamp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(true, missing, missing);
                        xlSamp.Quit();
```

- Make sure the filename and folder path do not contain more than 218 characters.

> This error comes when your location path will be to long reduce path

- Make sure the specified folder exists.
- Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.

> Make sure your location folder must exists on that location and give
> read write permission to that folder

- Make sure the filename and folder path do not contain any of the following characters:  <  >  ?  [  ]  :  | or  *

> give folder name and filename proper format